# What is the best way to create a splash page in SP 2010 that contains just a picture and a list of languages

Tags: visual-studio, page-layout, publishing, custom-masterpage

Do I need to create a new master page? what should be included in this master page regarding that I don't what a menu, footer, logo, and nothing but my picture and a list of languages and flags. I'm using SPS 2010 (publishing site) The entire project is in vs 2010. I've already created a page layout and a page but how can I get rid of the header other surrounding controls (the best way)?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

I'm answering my question. maybe it helps someone else. The best way I found is:
1- create a new minimal masterpage and hide everything that is not required the masterpage should be packaged in a Module item in visual studio with an elements file to put the master page in Master Pages catalog in sharepoint.
2- Create a new Page template and put whatever you need in this page
3- Then you need to set the page's MasterPageFile property to the minimal master page that you have created in step 1. This step is tricky but simple. You just need to create a class that inherits from Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PublishingLayoutPage, override OnPreInit and call the original OnPreInit and then set the property to somthing like this: "/_catalogs/masterpage/whatever_you_named_it.master"
4- Create a feature and package and deploy it

Answer (score 0):

What I usually do for these special "landing" pages (or 404 pages) is to make sure that I have sufficient ContentPlaceHolder within my main master page around all major UI component (header, footer, navigation, ...) that way I'm making them empty in the page layout that I'm using for these special pages and finally relying on the AdditionalPageHead place holder to inject some page specific css classes to would take care of unforeseen branding / removal.

Hope it helps.